# jQuery to target unique data-post_id

Tags: jquery

Here is what I am trying to do. For my custom loop, the data are pulled by the `data-post_id`.

Now, I have a `show_button` button that has the unique post id. There is another div container which also has the same unique post_id. This div is initially hidden and I want to show this when the `"show_button"` is clicked.

How can I target the unique post_id to show? (my script is not working).

```
<?php echo '<button id="show_button" type="button" data-post_id="' . esc_attr( $post->id ) . '">' ;?>
    Show Button
<?php echo '</button>';?>   

<?php echo '<div id="yay"  style="display:none" data-post_id="' . esc_attr( $post->id ) . '">' ;?>
    Yay
<?php echo '</div>';?>  


<script>
jQuery('#show_button').click(function(){
     jQuery("#yay[data-post_id='" + $(this).data("post_id") + "']").show();
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Had a typo (product_id instead of post_id) when I wrote the question. The question is now fixed. Thanks.

Comment: The `div` tag uses `data-product_id` rather than `data-post_id`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Opps, it is supposed to be post_id. (typo when I typed the question). :P

Comment: This code is inside a loop?

Comment: Could you show us the generated code (View Source in your browser)? I hard-coded your html in a test file, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: What's the point of using an attribute selector when the selector is for an ID? IDs have to be unique, so there's only one `#yay`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your selector is incorrect. You want to target `#yay[data-product_id` to show. The way it's currently written, you're looking for a div with ID of yay and a data-post_id attribute instead of targeting a div with a data-product_id attribtue.

Comment: The entire line would be: ` jQuery("#yay[data-product_id='" + $(this).data("post_id") + "']").show();`

Comment: @user2705632 Put the corrected code in the answer, not a comment.